# Select rows between two dates - recent 3 month period -

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, valueerror

I have a data frame, and I'm trying to select rows between two dates (recent 3 months period), and I found this solution [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates/).

this is the head of my dataframe

```
        week    storeA  storeB  storeC  storeD  storeE
0   2014-05-04  2643    8257    3893    6231    1294
1   2014-05-11  6444    5736    5634    7092    2907
2   2014-05-18  9646    2552    4253    5447    4736
3   2014-05-25  5960    10740   8264    6063    949
4   2014-06-01  7412    7374    3208    3985    3023
```

First, I convert the column 'week' of my dataframe to datetime64[ns] format:

```py
    df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['week'])
```

I get the start and end dates like this

```py
    start_date = pd.to_datetime(df.tail(1)['week'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3))
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(df.tail(1)['week']) 

    # start_date : 199   2017-11-25 Name: week, dtype: datetime64[ns] 
    #end_date : 199   2018-02-25 Name: week, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then I tried to select rows:

```py
    mask = (df['week'] > start_date) & (df['week'] <= end_date)
    df.loc[mask]
```

Here I get this error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I tried to write dates as a string and it works:

```py
    mask = (df['week'] > '2017-11-25') & (df['week'] <= '2018-02-25')
    df.loc[mask]
```

I tried to convert start date to string and it works

```py
    start_date = str(start_date)[6:16]
    end_date = str(end_date)[6:16]
```

So, what causes the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following your code, I found that the data type of both 'start_date' and 'end_date' is Series (NOT Timestamp like df['week']). Check by:

```
type(df['week'][0]), type(start_date)
```

Then they cannot be compared.
You may try this code:
`id = start_date.index[0]`

`start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date[id])`

Note: "id" stores the index (based on your data, it is 199.)

Comment: yes that right type(df['week'][0]) is <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> and type(start_date) is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: how we can convert it to Timestamp?

Comment: I tried to convert it with this method : Series.to_timestamp(freq=None, how='start', copy=True) but it gaves me that error : AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_timestamp'

Comment: See my revised version :-)